# What is the cap on trade ships increasing Harbour resource capacity?

Tags: kittens-game

[Cargo Ships](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=ship&redirect=no) upgrade increases Harbour capacity with more trade ships, and the Wiki says it does this with diminishing returns, but I noticed that the trade ship effect suddenly stopped completely, not diminished gradually.

Could someone explain how the behavior really works?

Comment: [Here's how diminishing returns works](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Diminishing+Returns). I'll post a full answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh -- my mistake:

clarification:

With 303.670 ships, my Harbour capacity is 7711.224catnip / 23.459Kwood / 31.837K minerals / 5026.947 iron / 948.481 coal / 158.080 gold / 316.160 titanium.

With 308.400 ships, my Harbour capacity is 7721.215catnip / 23.489Kwood / 31.879K minerals / 5033.460 iron / 949.709 coal / 158.285 gold / 316.570 titanium.

So I guess I hit the Diminishing Returns knee in the curve, I was expecting it to be more gradual.